# Remove Bing Maps Pushpins with separate button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, bing-maps, pushpin

currently I can display pushpins onto my Bing Maps but I would simply like to remove them when another button is pressed, in this case I would be calling it BTNReset. This is just to make the maps a little more tidy when it becomes clustered so the user can remove all uneccessary pushpins.

```
Private Sub Berwickshire() Handles BTNCounty.Click
    If TXTCounty.Text = "Berwickshire" Then

        Dim CountyLocation(20) As Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location
        CountyLocation(0) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.705617, -2.4676497)
        CountyLocation(1) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.780619, -2.3413039)
        CountyLocation(2) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.720304, -2.2638738)
        CountyLocation(3) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.746443, -2.2271899)
        CountyLocation(4) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.808939, -2.4924539)
        CountyLocation(5) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.882232, -2.3064212)
        CountyLocation(6) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.852663, -2.3889276)
        CountyLocation(7) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.802325, -2.2096172)
        CountyLocation(8) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.651853, -2.252035)
        CountyLocation(9) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.690431, -2.3361588)
        CountyLocation(10) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.645024, -2.3311619)
        CountyLocation(11) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.932739, -2.3614317)
        CountyLocation(12) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.870455, -2.0969097)
        CountyLocation(13) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.852035, -2.1896638)
        CountyLocation(14) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.887334, -2.1601164)
        CountyLocation(15) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.841716, -2.1222754)
        CountyLocation(16) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.771675, -2.803132)
        CountyLocation(17) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.719837, -2.750872)
        CountyLocation(18) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.680163, -2.5615687)
        CountyLocation(19) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.741492, -2.5838242)
        CountyLocation(20) = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(55.637369, -2.6798897)
        Dim names = New String() {
       "Greenlaw",
       "Duns",
       "Swinton",
       "Whitsome",
       "Longformacus",
       "Grantshouse",
       "Abbey St Bathans",
       "Chirnside",
       "Coldstream",
       "Leitholm",
       "Birgham",
       "Cockburnspath",
       "Eyemouth",
       "Reston",
       "Coldingham",
       "Ayton",
       "Oxton",
       "Lauder",
       "Gordon",
       "Westruther",
       "Earlston"}





        For index = 0 To CountyLocation.Length - 1
            Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()

            Dim CoordinateTip = New System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip()
            CoordinateTip.Content = names(index)

            Pin.Location = CountyLocation(index)
            Pin.ToolTip = CoordinateTip
            BingMap.Children.Add(Pin)



        Next




    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do BingMap.Children.Clear() to remove all data on the map.